# Cannot access service from external IP azure devops kubernetes

Tags: kubernetes, azure-devops

I can obtain my service by running

```
$ kubectl get service <service-name> --namespace <namespace name>

NAME          TYPE           CLUSTER-IP  EXTERNAL-IP  PORT(S)       AGE
service name  LoadBalancer   *********   *********    port numbers  16h
```

here is my service running at kubernetes but I can't access it through public IP. below are my service and deployment files added . i am using azre devops to build and release container image to azure container registry . As you see above on service describe i got external ip and cluster ip but when i try this ip in browser or use curl i get no response.   `

```
{
  "kind": "Service",
  "apiVersion": "v1",
  "metadata": {
    "name": "service-name",
    "namespace": "namespace-name",
    "selfLink": "*******************",
    "uid": "*******************",
    "resourceVersion": "1686278",
    "creationTimestamp": "2019-07-15T14:12:11Z",
    "labels": {
      "run": "service name"
    }
  },
  "spec": {
    "ports": [
      {
        "protocol": "TCP",
        "port": 80,
        "targetPort": ****,
        "nodePort": ****
      }
    ],
    "selector": {
      "run": "profile-management-service"
    },
    "clusterIP": "**********",
    "type": "LoadBalancer",
    "sessionAffinity": "None",
    "externalTrafficPolicy": "Cluster"
  },
  "status": {
    "loadBalancer": {
      "ingress": [
        {
          "ip": "*************"
        }
      ]
    }
  }
}
{
  "kind": "Deployment",
  "apiVersion": "extensions/v1beta1",
  "metadata": {
    "name": "deployment-name",
    "namespace": "namespace-name",
    "selfLink": "*************************",
    "uid": "****************************",
    "resourceVersion": "1686172",
    "generation": 1,
    "creationTimestamp": "2019-07-15T14:12:04Z",
    "labels": {
      "run": "deployment-name"
    },
    "annotations": {
      "deployment.kubernetes.io/revision": "1"
    }
  },
  "spec": {
    "replicas": 1,
    "selector": {
      "matchLabels": {
        "run": "deployment-name"
      }
    },
    "template": {
      "metadata": {
        "creationTimestamp": null,
        "labels": {
          "run": "deployment-name"
        }
      },
      "spec": {
        "containers": [
          {
            "name": "deployment-name",
            "image": "dev/containername:50",
            "ports": [
              {
                "containerPort": ****,
                "protocol": "TCP"
              }
            ],
            "resources": {},
            "terminationMessagePath": "/dev/termination-log",
            "terminationMessagePolicy": "File",
            "imagePullPolicy": "IfNotPresent"
          }
        ],
        "restartPolicy": "Always",
        "terminationGracePeriodSeconds": 30,
        "dnsPolicy": "ClusterFirst",
        "securityContext": {},
        "schedulerName": "default-scheduler"
      }
    },
    "strategy": {
      "type": "RollingUpdate",
      "rollingUpdate": {
        "maxUnavailable": 1,
        "maxSurge": 1
      }
    },
    "revisionHistoryLimit": 2147483647,
    "progressDeadlineSeconds": 2147483647
  },
  "status": {
    "observedGeneration": 1,
    "replicas": 1,
    "updatedReplicas": 1,
    "readyReplicas": 1,
    "availableReplicas": 1,
    "conditions": [
      {
        "type": "Available",
        "status": "True",
        "lastUpdateTime": "2019-07-15T14:12:04Z",
        "lastTransitionTime": "2019-07-15T14:12:04Z",
        "reason": "MinimumReplicasAvailable",
        "message": "Deployment has minimum availability."
      }
    ]
  }
}
```

`

Comment: can you please share the serivce and deployment yaml file if possible?

Comment: duplicate of [kubernetes pods shows warning](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57039555/kubernetes-pods-shows-warning). please, do not create duplicate questions

Comment: I think is not a duplicate question, can you share some context? service and deployment yaml?

Comment: steps:
- task: Kubernetes@1
  displayName: 'kubectl service'
  inputs:
    kubernetesServiceEndpoint: kubernetesconnection
    namespace: namespacename
    command: run
    arguments: 'service --image dev/app:$(Build.BuildId)  --port 8083'
    azureSubscriptionEndpointForSecrets: '*********************'
    azureContainerRegistry: **********
    secretName: regsecret
  enabled: false

Comment: steps:
- task: Kubernetes@1
  displayName: 'kubectl deployment'
  inputs:
    kubernetesServiceEndpoint: kubernetesconnection
    namespace: kubnamespace
    command: expose
    arguments: 'deployment deploymentname --type=LoadBalancer --port 80 --target-port 8083 --name=service-name'
    azureSubscriptionEndpointForSecrets: '********************'
    azureContainerRegistry: registry
    secretName: regsecret
    versionSpec: 1.7.0
    checkLatest: true
  enabled: false
  condition: succeededOrFailed()

Comment: @harsh and wolmi please have a look at these yaml files

Comment: @4c74356b41 if you think they are of same context you can answer there to resolve  issue

Comment: @bilal_khan please run `kubectl get service <service name> -o yaml` and `kubectl get deployment <deployment name> -o yaml` and edit your question to paste it as a code block?

Comment: @wolmi please have a look

Comment: @bilal_khan are you sure yor deployment labels and service lable value are same so that both can create the connection.

Comment: yes they are same

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Apparently there's a mismatch in label and selector:

Service selector

```
"selector": {
      "run": "profile-management-service"
```

While deployment label

```
"labels": {
      "run": "deployment-name"
    },
```

Also check **targetPort** value of the service, it should match **containerPort** of your deployment

Comment: target port and container port wasnt same . Thanks . now working

Answer (score 0):

You need to add `readinessProbe` and `livenessProbe` on your Deployment and after that check your firewall if all rules are correct.

[Here](https://kubernetes.io/docs/tasks/configure-pod-container/configure-liveness-readiness-probes/) you have some more info about liveness and readiness